# Why is onAuthorization executing before authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization

I'm trying to do some custom authorization so I created a controller overriding the `OnAuthorization` method. I also applied the `Authorize` attribute to this controller.
The question is why is the `OnAuthorization` method called BEFORE the basic forms authentication process?

I would like to authorize the user after he is authenticated.
Am I missing something?

Here is the code:

```
[Authorize]
    public class AuthorizationController : Controller
    {
        protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

            if (filterContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
            }

            List<string> allowedControllers = new List<string>() { "SecurityController" };
            List<string> allowedActions = new List<string>() { "Index" };

            string controllerName = filterContext.Controller.GetType().Name;
            string actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

            if (!allowedControllers.Contains(controllerName)
            || !allowedActions.Contains(actionName))
            {
                filterContext.Result = View("UnauthorizedAccess");
            }
        }
    }
```

The controller that I tested with is something like:

```
public class SecurityController : AuthorizationController
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult AnotherIndex()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One of the first things the `AuthorizeAttribute` does is check to see if the user is authenticated. If they are not then that is when a redirect to the login page will be issued.

The `AuthorizeAttribute` basically wraps the authentication check in with the authorization piece:

```
protected virtual bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
        if (httpContext == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
        }

        IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            return false;
        }
```

When you use the AuthorizeAttribute with no roles/users as you do in your example ([Authorize]), it is basically just checking to make sure the user is authenticated in this case.

I would probably change your code to override the AuthorizeAttribute instead of doing this code in your controller. You can do the following:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = CreateResult(filterContext);
    }

    protected ActionResult CreateResult(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(filterContext.RequestContext, filterContext.Controller);
        var controller = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var action = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        // any custom model here
        var model = new UnauthorizedModel(); 

        // custom logic to determine proper view here - i'm just hardcoding it
        var viewName = "~/Views/Shared/Unauthorized.cshtml"; 

        return new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = viewName,
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<UnauthorizedModel>(model)
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it does not happen as I expect it to. For the above example, when I want to access the AnotherIndex action, I would expect to get the login page, but I am getting UnauthorizedAccess.

Comment: After your edit: I understand, but if I override the AuthorizeAttribute, I don't have access to make other actions like redirecting the user to a page that tells him he is not authorized instead of not logged in...

Comment: @misha Sure you do. What makes you think you can't?

Comment: Can I make that from the httpContext? How?

Comment: I tried it, but seems to work the same. Index is returning to the login page, but AnotherIndex is not giving me the login page instead I get the Unauthorize view (which should happen only if the user is logged in)

Comment: @misha I would have to be able to help you. Did you remove the code from the controller and just have an attribute?

Comment: Yes, I did. Now it's like [CustomAuthorizeAttribute]public class SecurityController : Controller. Thank you any way, I gave you +1 for the effort, but I think I'm missing some kind of a configuration.

Comment: @misha Go ahead and update the question with the new code. It might help me see why it is not working.

Comment: I was too tired yesterday, and I think I didn't understood how authentication works. I just needed to add an {if else} to see if the user is authenticated, which you explained in your initial post..

Answer (score 2):

Following is a sample for Custom Authorization Attribute.

```
 public class AuthLogAttribute:AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        public string View { get; set; }

        public AuthLogAttribute()
        {
            View = "AuthorizeFailed";
        }
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)

        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            IsUserAuthorized(filterContext);
        }

        private void IsUserAuthorized(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            // If the Result returns null then the user is Authorized 
            if(filterContext.Result ==null)
                return;

            //If the user is Un-Authorized then Navigate to Auth Failed View 
            if(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)

            {
                var vr = new ViewResult();
                vr.ViewName = View;

                ViewDataDictionary dict = new ViewDataDictionary();
                dict.Add("Message", "Sorry you are not Authorized to Perform this Action");
                vr.ViewData = dict;

                var result = vr;
                filterContext.Result = vr;
            }

        }
    }
```

Your Controller will be like following,

```
 [AuthLog(Roles ="Manager")]     
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var product = new Product();
            return View(product);
        }
```

Finally create new Shared view Call "AuthorizeFailed".

Comment: This worked well for me.  You can find the Roles that are authorized with a simple this.Roles and compare with your filterContext.HttpContext.User roles to do your own authorization and redirect using the above code if not authed.

Comment: whats is result=vr for?

Answer (score -2):

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    bool flag = false;
    string UserId;
    string[] AssignedRights = null;

    //Check if Http Context Contains User Name
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name != string.Empty)
    {
        //Get User Id from HttpContext
        UserId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        RoleRepository roleRepository = new RoleRepository();
        AssignedRights = roleRepository.GetRolesByUser(Convert.ToInt32(UserId));
        flag = IsUserAuthorized(filterContext, flag, AssignedRights);

        if (flag == false)
       {

           filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }

}
```