# How to return to login page from an filter which inherits from AuthorizationFilterAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, form-authentication

In method `public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)` I am validating the user, if not successful, I want to land to the login page.

I am using Form Authentication where `loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn"` is mentioned.

Comment: Try looking to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366085/why-is-onauthorization-executing-before-authentication

Comment: AuthorizationFilterAttribute belong to System.Web.Http.Filters.
Hence I am looking for a solution for my API controllers filter.

Comment: `System.Web.Http` types are for Web API. Why would you want to "return to the login page" from a Web API call? Think about that for a minute. How is the program that is calling the API supposed to work with a login page?

Comment: I agree.

Actually its a Ajax call on click of a button within the application and session has timeout.

That's why I needed to be on the login page.

I am able to land on login page from filter for normal controllers.

Comment: That makes more sense. But I suggest you **edit your question** to add that relevant information. Not everyone reads all of the comments.